# Firemonkey Gesture pan and panel position

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a `Tpanel` into my Firemonkey android Form and also a web browser control i am try to set the `position.x` of the `tpanel` dynamically  when i move my finger to right screen  i do something like following

```
procedure TForm1.webrowser1Gesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin

if EventInfo.GestureID = igiPan then
begin
Handled := True;

panel1.Position.x := EventInfo.Location.X;


end;


end;
```

but the panel1 position seems not changes at all what i am doing wrong ?

i already dropped `TGestureManager` and set the gesture pan and in the webbrowser Touch property